# Play m4p with AudioQueue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-audio

Is it possible to play protected m4p files with AudioQueue?
I tried NSSound (it can play m4p) and the AudioQueue sample afplay (does not work otb). Is there any way to play m4p with AudioQueue?

Comment: or can I play m4v with QTKit? (tried the apple QTKitPlayer example, but it crashes when I try to open an .m4p file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I discovered so far:

`AudioQueue`: no m4p support, because quicktime is responsible for the encryption.

`NSSound`: supports m4p (I assume that it is using quicktime to do it) but it definitely sucks at large sound files. (playback quality problems and performance problems)

`QTKit`: Can play m4p but only if you are not starting from Xcode or the `gdb`. It looks like this is a protection mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

2014: NSSound does not support M4P. AIFF, WAV and NeXT SND file formats only.